# Parsing JavaScript Array for specific value

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I've a JavaScript Array like

```
var main = [
 { "title": "Yes", "path": "images/main_buttons/tick_yes.png"},
 { "title": "No", "path": "images/main_buttons/cross_no.png"},
]
```

I want to get the corresponding `path` value for the item which have a particular `title` value.

Something like

```
var temp = "Yes";
var result = (path value where main[0].title == temp);
```

I want to get the `result` value here.

If `temp == "No"`, it should get me the corresponding `path` value.

Comment: That's not a JSON string, that's a JavaScript array (of JavaScript objects).

Comment: You'd need to loop over `main` and compare each elements `.title` value until you found the right one.

Comment: If you control the generation of this code, you could just make it an associative array, like `var arr = ["yes":"someval","no","someotherval"]` and access them with `arr["yes"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Array.prototype.filter` method:

```
var result = main.filter(function(o) {
    return o.title === temp;
});

var path = result.length ? result[0].path : null;
```

Please note that older browsers do not the support the `.filter()` method. However, you can use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this

```
function getPath(title, arr) {
    for (var i=arr.length;i--;) {
        if (arr[i].title == title) return arr[i].path;
    }
}
```

called like

```
getPath('Yes', main); // returns the path or undefined
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/v36Mf/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
var myItem = (function(arr, val){
  for(var item in arr){
    if(!arr.hasOwnProperty(item) && arr[item].title == val){
      return arr[item];
    }
  }
  return null;
})(myJSArray, "valueToMatch");
```